# PHP echo problem

Tags: php

What is wrong in the following code?

```
<?php
    echo "<td class='column1'><a href='#' OnClick='windowpopup(". secure_base_url()`"product/item/". $itemid ."/); return false;'>$row->title</a></td>";?>
?>
```

Why doesn't a popup window come up?

Comment: Ah ha! Hidden HTML due to bad formatting!

Answer (score 5):

### After OP Clarification:

After viewing hidden HTML, I must say here's how your code should look like:

```
<?php
echo "<td class='column1'><a href='#' OnClick='windowpopup(\"". secure_base_url() ."product/item/". $itemid ."/\"); return false;'>{$row->title}</a></td>";
?>
```

The reason is same though. You need to escape correctly and use double quotes for variables to expand in PHP.

### Old Answer

Use this:

```
 echo "{$row->title}";
```

Or

```
 echo $row->title;
```

The [PHP String Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) says that:

> "The most important feature of double-quoted strings is the fact that variable names will be expanded."

So, to expand variable names, either use double quotes and as precaution enclose them in `{}` *OR* do not use quotes at all.

Answer (score 2):

String interpolation in PHP only works in **double quotes**.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the value of `$row->title`. Also, using single quotes will print the variable name, rather than its value.

**edit:** Ahh so there is more. Shamittomar, seems to have fixed your problem =)

Comment: The second sentence is enough to answer the question :)

Comment: Yup =) Was trying to figure out why he 'can't popup window'.

Comment: the popup code was being concealed and I've fixed the question.